# What different between Proxy and Delegate in iOS design mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

What different between Proxy and Delegate in iOS design?
I am reading project there I have not seen the design patterns, A small number of Proxy, else is Delegate.

Any difference between them?

```
@protocol BaseViewControllerProxy <NSObject> 

@optional

- (void)updateLayout:(CGRect)rect;
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;  @optional

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize;
- (void)viewWillAnimateTransitionToSize;
- (void)viewDidTransitionToSize;
- (void)viewWillTransitionFrom:(UITraitCollection *)oldCollection toTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection;
- (void)viewWillAnimateTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection;
- (void)viewDidTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Proxy` and `Delegate` are very different, these are some of the things I could think of :

`Proxy` pattern is useful in the case where a huge local database is involved and you do not want to create an instance of the real object in one call. (i.e. you have 1000 products, but you do want to load 100 by 100, you can load all 100 objects, then load the other 900 objects with proxy that carries the object's primary key.) I believe this pattern helps in memory management and this is just one of the use cases I for NSProxy. More about [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) here.

`Delegate` pattern is mainly used to act as a `HQ Commander`. Delegate is like an object that act on behalf of another. A very common use case is when a `button` lies deep inside a `tableview cell` and you need to handle such action from its `view controller`, hence you need to give the `tableview cell` a `HQ Commander` which in this case we will set as the `view controller`. So everytime the `button` is tapped, the `HQ Commander` is notified, and the `view controller` will carry out its implemented task,